# How can I use a tv as monitor?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I'm currently running Ubuntu of the live CD.

I have a 22" TV  that is rarely used and I would like to connect it permanently to my computer as a sole monitor.

My PC has only a VGA and S video output.  (No DVI or HDMI)  The TV has VGA, HDMI,
 & S Video outputs. It has inbuilt freeview & DVD player.

I have just tried it by powering up the TV and attaching the VGA cable but no luck. it does not recognise the computer and all i get is the Red Freeview banner across the screen.
 Could this be because ubuntu is running off the CD as opposed to the HDD.
Could you explain in steps any settings I need to change to get the PC to recognise the TV monitor.  also do I just plug my audio speakers into the green port to get sound.
Thanks

Comment: Yes you need to install Ubuntu to be able to use it fully.

Comment: TVs usually have a way to change the input. Make sure that the input in the TV is set to VGA.

Comment: Thanks guys.  tuned the TV to VGA connected up and all brilliant.  even got the correct resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To test the system before installing, make sure and hook up the tv first with machine in off and tv on then boot off live cd then tv should come on this is a good test for any device that you want to test with Linux or Ubuntu: wifi, tv, monitors, printers, etc.

Plug in before the live boot, then, if it works, it work after a install if not a install will not help.

Answer (score 0):

> TVs usually have a way to change the input. Make sure that the input
>   in the TV is set to VGA

from @user68186 comment.